# Is there a correspondence between these sets of areas?

Tags: probability, number-theory, probability-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers

Given are two functions, $p(x)$ and $\phi(x)$, defined as follows
$$
\begin{align}
p\colon [3, +\infty[ &\to [0, 1],\\
x &\mapsto \frac{1}{\ln x},
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\phi\colon \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}\setminus\{1\} &\to \mathbb{R},\\
x &\mapsto 2^{\frac{1}{\ln x}}.
\end{align}
$$

Given any real $r\ge4$ let $T_r$ be the solution of $\phi(x)=x/r$ and let $N_r$ be the solution of $p(x)=x/r.$

Do the following bijective correspondences between sets of areas hold?

$A=\{\int_0^{T_1} \phi(x)dx, \int_0^{T_2} \phi(x)dx,..., \int_0^1 \phi(x)dx\},$ where $T_1<T_2<...<1.$

$B=\{\int_3^{N_1} p(x)dx, \int_3^{N_2} p(x)dx,...,\int_3^{\infty} p(x)dx\},$ where $N_1<N_2<...<\infty.$

$A \mapsto B,$ such that the first element in $A$ maps to the first element in $B,$ the second element in $A$ maps to the second element of $B,$ and so on.

My perspective on this problem is that $A\mapsto B$ because every area in $A$ can be assigned to every area in $B.$ Each area greater than $1$ can be associated to an area in $[0,1].$ I'm not sure how to prove or disprove this implication, that the finite quantity can be assigned to the infinite one. How would I do this?

Comment: What is $p(x)$ exactly? "$p(x)$ is some function that spits out a probability of an event happening" isn't a good description

Comment: $p(x)$ is unitless, so in theory it's kosher to exponentiate it. It's more common to instead look at $\exp(\ln(p(x))$, and to then study $\ln(p(x))$ for especially rare events in Large Deviations Theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_deviations_theory

Comment: Can you rewrite the question so that it becomes clearer, please? For example: from first line I understand that the probability of event $1/e$ is $-1$. How can this happen?

Comment: forgot to note that $x \ge 3$

Comment: You define $\zeta_x \in(0,1) \times(0,1)$ and $L_x \in(1,\infty) \times (1,\infty)$, but where are they used then?

Comment: @simonet they are just the two different regions in which the function $\phi(x)$ lives

Comment: Functons do not _live_; functions _are defined_ on sets and _take values_ on sets. You defined $p(x)\colon [3, +\infty[ \to [0,1]$, so I imagine that $\phi(x) \colon [3, +\infty[ \to [1,2]$. I still cannot see the connection with $\zeta_x$ and with $L_x$.

Comment: @simonet when $p(x)$ is raised to the power of $2$ this is different than simply $p(x)$ alone. $\phi(x)$ is not defined at $x=0,1$

Comment: $\phi(x)$ is defined in $x \in (0,1)$ and $\phi \in (0,1)$ as well as $x \in (1,\infty)$ and $\phi \in (1,\infty)$

Comment: Ok, so $\phi \colon (0,\infty)\setminus\{1\} \to (0,\infty)\setminus\{1\}$. Now, what is your question? What do you mean with "correspondence between areas"? Are you asking to find $T$ and $N$ such that the two integrals give the same result?

Comment: No I'm asking if there is a bijection between the two areas

Comment: Then what are $T$ and $N$? In the phrase "Set $f(x)=ϕ(x)$ to find the upper bound of the integral" what is $f$ and which integral are you referring to?

Comment: What does it mean to put an arrow between two integrals? Are you just asking whether they are equal?

Comment: For example setting the line $x/5=\phi(x)$ yields approximately $x=.702$ This is $T$ the upper bound on the integral for $\phi(x).$ And $x/5=p(x)$ yields approximately $x=3.769$ This is the upper bound $N$ on the integral for $p(x)$

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm asking if there is a bijection between the two areas

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a bijection between areas. Integrals are numbers – what's a bijection between two numbers? If you're asking for a bijection between two *regions* in the plane, well, each region contains a continuum of points, so they have the same cardinality, so of course there's a bijection. Maybe you could give an example of a bijection between two areas, so we could see what you mean.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I updated the question to give an example

Comment: So you want to know whether it's true that $\int_0^T\phi(x)=\int_2^Np(x)$ provided $T$ and $N$ are as defined in the question, right?

Comment: But now I don't understand what you mean by $f(x)=mx=\phi(x)$ and $f(x)=p(x)$. What's $f(x)$? What's $m$? What's $T_1$? What's $N_1$? I think you still need an example if anyone is going to understand you.

Comment: I *think* what you are saying is, given any real $r$, let $T=T_r$ be the solution of $\phi(x)=rx$ and let $N=N_r$ be the solution of $p(x)=rx$. Please edit the body of the question so that these things are clear, and so that no one has to read through all the comments to understand what you mean.

Comment: Please engage with my comments, Ultra.

Comment: Yes I edited the question with your suggestion

Comment: Yet not clear for me: $r$ cannot be _any_ real: for example it cannot be $0$. Furthermore: you cannot integrate $p(x)$ from $2$ to another value, since $p$ is not defined in $[2, 3[$.

Comment: @simonet okay I made changes

Comment: It still does not work: if $r = 1$, the solution of $p(x) = x/r$ is $x \approx 1.8$, which is not in the range of definition of $p$. I suggest you to consider taking some time to re-formulate the problem so that it will be clear for everyone. I think that there will be no answers to the question until it does not appear like a clear, well-formulated problem. It could be useful (for you and for the reader) trying to explain the attempts you made for tackling the problem.

Comment: @simonet Maybe the source of confusion for people is that a finite area is being associated to an infinite area

Comment: We're up to version 23, and the question is still incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn’t verify the claims below, but they seems to be plausible for me. Are they answer your question?

Since we consider only $T_r<1$, it will be convenient for us to restrict the domain of the function $\phi(x)$ to $(0,1)$. Since for  any  fixed $x>0$ the function $x/r$ is decreasing and both functions $p(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ are continuous and decreasing on their domains, $p(3)>3/4$, and $\lim_{x\to +0}\phi(x)=1$, we have that the functions $N_r$ and $T_r$ are defined for $r\in [4,+\infty[$, are continuous and increasing,  see the illustrations. 
[image]

[image]

Thus  functions  $\Phi(r)=\int_0^{T_r}\phi(x)dx$ and $P(r)=\int_3^{N_r}p(x)dx$ also are defined for $r\in [4,+\infty[$, are continuous and increasing. Therefore each area $\Phi(r)\in \left[\int_0^{T_4}\phi(x)dx, \int_0^1\phi(x)dx\right[$ determines a unique value $r$, which determines a unique area $P(r)\in \left[\int_3^{P_4}p(x)dx, \infty\right[$, and this bijection $\Phi(r)\to P(r)$ is increasing and continuous.